# Decrementing an off the end iterator

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

I was reading today about how for containers that support bidirectional iteration, this piece of code is valid:

```
Collection c(10, 10);
auto last = --c.end();
*last;
```

That got me thinking, is it required that when submitting a pair of bidirectional iterators [beg, end) to an algorithm in the STL that --end is defined? If so, should the result be dereferenceable?

ie

```
void algo(T beg, T end){
    //...
    auto iter = --end;
    //...
    *iter;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the algorithm requires a range defined by bidirectional iterators `first` and `last`, then `--last` needs to be valid under the same conditions that `++first` does -- namely that the range isn't empty. The range is empty if and only if `first == last`.

If the range isn't empty, then `--last` evaluates to an iterator that refers to the last element in the range, so `*--last` indeed also needs to be valid.

That said, there aren't all that many standard algorithms that require specifically a bidirectional iterator (and don't require random-access). `prev`, `copy_backward`, `move_backward`, `reverse`, `reverse_copy`, `stable_partition`, `inplace_merge`, `[prev|next]_permutation`.

If you look at what some of those do, you should see that typically the algorithm does decrement the end-of-range iterator and dereference the result.

As James says, for containers the function `end()` returns an iterator *by value*. There is no general requirement that for iterators that `--x` should be a well-formed expression when `x` is an rvalue of the type. For example, pointers are bidirectional iterators, and a function declared as `int *foo();` returns a pointer by value, and `--foo()` is not a well-formed expression. It just so happens that for the containers you've looked at in your implementation, `end()` returns a class type which has `operator--` defined as a member function, and so the code compiles. It also works since the container isn't empty.

Be aware that there is a difference in this respect between:

```
auto last = --c.end();
```

vs.

```
auto last = c.end();
--last;
```

The former decrements an rvalue, whereas the latter decrements an lvalue.

Answer (score 7):

You read wrong.  The expression `--c.end()` is never authorized.  If the
iterator isn't at least bidirectional, it is, in fact, expressedly
forbidden, and requires a compiler error.  If the collection is empty,
it is undefined behavior.  And in all other cases, it will work **if**
it compiles, but there is no guarantee that it will compile.  It failed
to compile with many early implementations of `std::vector`, for
example, where the iterator was just a typedef to a pointer.  (In fact,
I think formally that it is undefined behavior in all cases, since
you're violating a constraint on a templated implementation.  In
practice, however, you'll get what I just described.)

Arguably, because it isn't guaranteed, a good implementation will cause
it to fail to compile, systematically.  For various reasons, most don't.
Don't ask me why, because it's incredibly simple to get it to fail
systematically: just make the `operator--` on the iterator a free
function, rather than a member.

EDIT (additional information):

The fact that it isn't required is probably a large part of the
motivation behind `std::next` and `std::prev` in C++11.  Of course, 
every project I've worked on has had them anyway.  The correct way to
write this is:

```
prev( c.end() );
```

And of course, the constraints that the iterator be bidirectional or
better, and that the container not be empty, still hold.

Answer (score 1):

Each algorithm will tell you what type of iterator it requires. When a bidirectional iterator is called for, then naturally it will need to support decrementing.

Whether `--end` is possible depends on whether `end == beg`.

Comment: @SteveJessop: I don't agree with the edit. It doesn't matter what `beg` is, as long as `end` is not the same as `begin()`.

Comment: OK, if you revert it then I won't edit-war. However, no standard algorithm will wind an iterator back prior to the start point of the range it has been instructed to operate on, so although `--end` might be valid for some empty input ranges, the algorithm won't perform it and so it isn't *required* to be valid. Furthermore, "when submitting a pair of bidirectional iterators to an algorithm", there is no requirement that the iterators come from a container, so I didn't think that `begin()` should enter into it. Your version was true but (IMO) irrelevant to the question.

Comment: @SteveJessop: The iterators have to be comparable, though -- doesn't that imply that they have to come from the same container?

Comment: No, for example they could be pointers into an array, or they could be some user-defined bidirectional iterator that operates independently of any container. Off the top of my head I think all the standard iterators that are bi-directional, have to do with containers. But I might have forgotten something.

Comment: @SteveJessop: If they're pointers into an array, they definitely *have* to come from the same array, or it's UB. But I see how you could have more general situations without containers...

Comment: Sure, I'm only making a minor quibble that an array is not a container. The major quibble is that iterators needn't have anything to do with containers, and that the question is "is --end required to be valid", not "give an example of a circumstance under which --end is valid" :-)

Answer (score 0):

It's only required for algorithms that require bidirectional iterators.

Comment: It's not required then.  I've used implementations of `std::vector` where it wouldn't compile.