# Is it safe in C++ to subtract from container.end()?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, language-lawyer

That is, providing that `container` is not empty, can I safely do this:

```
std::vector<int> container;
container.push_back( 0xFACE8D );
auto last = container.end() - 1;
```

and this:

EDIT: replaced `-1` with `--` here:

```
std::list<int> container;
container.insert( 0xFACE8D );
auto last = container.end();
--last;
```

and again for arbitrary non-empty container?

EDIT: let me clarify the question.

Sometimes perfectly legal code behaves incorrectly. The question is: assuming that the above code compiles, is it safe to do something like that?

It should be safe for ordinary C-style arrays because the corresponding iterators are just pointers. But is it safe for more complicated containers?

Suppose that one implements list with iterators like this one:

```
class MyListIterator {
    MyListIterator *prev, *next;
    MyListIterator * operator--() { return prev; }
    ...
};

class MyList {
    MyListIterator *end() { return NULL; }
    ...
};
```

Then an attempt to decrement `container::end()`, despite being perfectly legal syntactically, would cause a segfault.

I hope, though, that `stl` containers are much smarter than that. Thus the question on the guarantees on the above `stl::list` code behavior, if any.

Comment: If it compiles, that means somebody went to the trouble of implementing `operator-()`, which strongly suggests they intended for you to call it...

Comment: @crayzeewulf: I'm not advocating that usage, just curious whether it's safe, have seeing something like that in the code.

Comment: @Kevin "It compiles so it must be okay" is a rather poor heuristic in C++.

Comment: @Michael Got it. I realized it after I saw `std::list` in the second case.

Comment: @Kevin: if everything that compiles would work correctly I would be a much happier person.

Comment: If your compiler accepts this with std::list, I will be quite surprised.

Comment: Which vindicates my comment: now that your code compiles, it is also correct.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12057046/decrementing-an-off-the-end-iterator

Comment: That would not be a conformant implementation of `std:list`. In a conformant implementation you can decrement the iterator returned by `end` as long as it is not the same iterator as is returned by `begin` -- that is, as long as the list isn't empty.

Comment: That's the reason why all node-based standard containers (list, (unordered)map/set) have allocating (and thus throwing) default constructors - they must allocate sentinel nodes to allow this kind of things - like going one step back from `end()`

Answer (score 10):

`std::vector` returns [random-access iterators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/RandomAccessIterator), so yes, this is safe with `vector`.

`std::list` returns [bidirectional iterators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/BidirectionalIterator). They can be incremented (`++`) and decremented (`--`), but don't allow for arbitrary arithmetic (`+`, `-`) or relative comparisons (`>`, `<`). It's not safe with `list`.

You can use [`std::advance`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance) on bidirectional iterators to advance or rewind arbitrary amounts. In C++11 you can use [`std::prev`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/prev) in place of `iter - 1`.

Comment: Nice catch. My question was somewhat different though; will add explanation in a sec.

Answer (score 3):

The C++ standard says that `std::vector<T>::iterator` is *random access iterator* pointing to the past-the-end element. So your can safely use `-` and `+` operators.

Unlike `std::vector`, `std::list<T>::iterator` is *bi-directional iterator* that support only `--` and `++` operators.