# Should begin() and end() methods in a container always have the same return type?

Tags: c++

I have an iterator that is heavier than an `int` or pointer (it is meant to iterate through the nearest neighbours of a site in a three-dimensional periodic lattice, so it must contain certain private support structures). To tell whether the iterator is at the end of the container I only need one comparison, but to create an iterator pointing to one-past end I would have to create also the support structurres.

I thus figured I could have the `end()` mehtod of the container return an `int`, and then overload `operator==()` to avoid creating a full one-past-end iterator.  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31457319/611697]) hints that it may be a good idea.  For bidirectional iterators it seems this is wrong, as I later learnt (from e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12057046/611697)) that whatever `end()` returns must be decrementable to the last element.

Since my iterator is only forward, I thought it would still be fine, but now I find I cannot use `std::find()` (and possibly other STL algorithms), which expects two arguments of the same (iterator) type.

So, my question is: is having `end()` return a type different than `begin()` a violation of standard behavior? Is it such a bad idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They must be the same type.

Changing this is the focus of some of the most hopeful range proposals. Its not a good requirement, but it is required, at least for now.

Comment: very clear.  I am not complying with the standard, so I can expect to be burnt.  If there's talk about changing it, I guess that what I was tryng to do was not such a bad idea. Would the change apply also to forward iterator? It seems that the requirement to be able to decrement from end() strongly collides with this attempted optimization.

Comment: The change would apply to every category of iterator, AFAIK. The requirement to be able to decrement end() would be dropped, I think.